# Responding to updates on SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an ImageButton that I want to use to set a boolean value for an item in an SQLiteDatabase.

The ImageButton will display one image for a value of "1", and another image for a value of "0". Pressing the image button should toggle the database field and therefore its image.

For some reason, when I press the button the value returned by the currentCursor.getInt() is still the same, despite the update method being called on the database. Do I have to update/refresh the cursor?

In my activity I have:

```
private void updateFavouriteButton(){

  int favourite = currentCursor.getInt(currentCursor.getColumnIndex(Object.favourite));

        if (favourite == 1)
        {
            favouriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favourite_selected));
            favouriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     dbHelper.updateFavourite(selectedId, 0);

                     updateFavouriteButton();
                 }
             });
        }
        else
        {
            favouriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favourite));
            favouriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     dbHelper.updateFavourite(selectedId, 1);

                     updateFavouriteButton();
                 }
             });
        }
}
```

In my database helper I have:

```
public void updateFavourite(long rowId, int favourite) 
    {


        db.beginTransaction();

        try {
             ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
             args.put("ZFAVOURITE", favourite);

            int rowsAffected = db.update("ZOBJECT", args,"_id" + "=" + rowId, null);

            if (rowsAffected > 0)
                db.setTransactionSuccessful(); 

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Error in transaction", e.toString());
        } finally {

            db.endTransaction();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

requery() is deprecated, the documentation says to just close the old cursor, remake it, and use the new one.

A cursor is a snapshot at the time its created. If the Database is changed, you must requery.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pyrodante had said, it is needed to `requery()` the cursor in some ways since `requery()` is deprecated

Not sure how u guys solve it, here is how I solve this problem.

please let me know if there is a better way. thanks!

```
Cursor newCursor=CreateCursor(); //ChreateCursor() create a method which returns you a new cursor

mAdapter.changeCursor(newCursor); //Change to the new cursor so that the list will be updated
```